# Oracle 11g sql%notfound issue

Tags: oracle, oracle11g

We have migrated our .database from oracle 8 to oracle 11g

in one of the procedure after update statement there is a if condition which checks whether any rows have been affected or not .
if yes then it would do nothing otherwise it would insert data into the table

```
IF (SQL%NOTFOUND) THEN
        -- The record does not exist so try to insert the master customer data.
        insert_order_master_customer(p_host_country_id,
                  p_order_id,             p_accting_year,
                  p_master_cust_id,
                  p_master_cust_name     );
    END IF;
```

but this condition is not working after successful update it's evaluating true and control is going inside if block.

Answer (score 1):

does not reproduce here on 11.2.0.2.

```
SQL> create table foo(id number);

Table created.

SQL> insert into foo values (1);

1 row created.

SQL> set serverout on
SQL> begin
  2    update foo set id = 2 where id = 1;
  3     IF (SQL%NOTFOUND) THEN
  4       dbms_output.put_line('not found!');
  5    elsif (SQL%NOTFOUND = false)
  6     then
  7       dbms_output.put_line('found!');
  8     end if;
  9  end;
 10  /
found!
```

is the update right before the check, ie nothing else sits between it? also what's the output if you put `dbms_output.put_line(sql%rowcount);` just before the IF check ?

Comment: yes update statement is right before the check. after update we have written commit; after that dbms_output.put_line(sql%rowcount); is giving zero rows . but if i write dbms_output.put_line(sql%rowcount); before commit it's giving 1 row .

Comment: @aru which is why i said is the update right before the check. with `COMMIT;`  sitting betweeen the update and sql% check i'd expect to have it return 0 for rowcount and true for notfound. you have to check the sql before doing any other sql including `commit;`

Comment: update sql is fine when i independently execute that it's executing correct.could you tell me  on successful update should sql% retun numbe rof rows updated of alwayz 0 ?

Comment: @aru sql%rowcount will return the number of rows updated. it will only return the correct value if you capture this before the commit or another SQL operation is done.

Comment: @aru ie. do `update x set a=... where ..;` then right after, before any commit something like `v_rows := sql%rowcount;` then you have the result and can commit or whatever, then later on you can check `if (v_rows > 0) then ..` (same goes for `sql%notfound`, just save to a boolean variable)

Comment: Wish u a very happy and prosperous new year.

Comment: yah that's i am going to do . but i am not able to understand why this code is working fine with oracle 8 . we are migrating the whole application and this condition could be at many places so do i need to make changes in all the places .please guide

Comment: i found this Yes,Here is what Oracle Support has to say about it:
=====
The behaviour you are observing is due to bug 2286387. You can set event 10943 to level 4194304 in your init<SID>.ora to get the old Oracle 8i behaviour. 

NOTE : The new behaviour in which SQL% attributes are affected by commit and rollback will be the DEFAULT behaviour going forward (Oracle 10i) so it is recommended to change the code so that you check the SQL% attrubutes before a commit or rollback. 
eleases.https://forums.oracle.com/forums/thread.jspa?threadID=209631

Answer (score 0):

```
exception when DATA_NOT_FOUND then

insert_order_master_customer(p_host_country_id,
                      p_order_id,             p_accting_year,
                      p_master_cust_id,
                      p_master_cust_name     );
```

Comment: is there any issue with SQL%notfound it's working fine in oracle 8

Comment: yes we have a update statement. just after we he commit and then we have a check IF (SQL%NOTFOUND) THEN  insert command end if . it's completely working fine in oracle 8 i.e after update it's not going within  if condition but after migrating to 11g it's not working even after successful update.

Answer (score 0):

1. Use SQL%ROWCOUNT for counting how many rows were affected. %NOTFOUND only works with Open-Fetch a cursor. SQL%NOTFOUND would TRUE inside a WHEN NO_DATA_FOUND exception.
2. It is, NO_DATA_FOUND, not DATA_NOT_FOUND